# How do you extract the maximum and minimum value from a nested array in N1QL query?

Tags: sql, database, couchbase, sql++

### **Background**

I'm am running the following query (I know it may be hard to read, so I'll clarify what it's doing afterwards):

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_bucket` AS a
    NEST (
    SELECT c.toNode, c.fromNode, d.endDateTime, d.startDateTime
    FROM `my_bucket` AS c
        JOIN (
        SELECT id, customAttributes.endDateTime, customAttributes.startDateTime
        FROM `my_bucket`
        WHERE type='airNode'
            AND customAttributes.endDateTime >= CLOCK_UTC()
            AND customAttributes.endDateTime <= DATE_ADD_STR(CLOCK_UTC(), 14, 'day')) AS d ON c.toNode = d.id
        AND c.type='relNode') b ON a.id = b.fromNode AND a.type='edNode';
```

Essentially, what's happening here is that we're pulling the relevant airNodes from the database, and joining them with the relNodes where relNodes.toNode = airNodes.id (toNode and id are fields from their respective nodes). Then, we're joining these relAirNodes with edNodes, and the statement returns with the following structure:

```
[ { 'edNode':..., 'relAirNodes':[{...},{...}] },...]
```

So essentially, we're getting an array of pairs, where each pair consists of one edNode and an array of relAirNodes.

### Question

Each relAirNode in the arrays of relAirNodes has an endTime and startTime field. Is there a way to run the query such that the return result is an array of pairs, the first element of the pair being an editNode and **the second element of the pair being a single struct with the minimum startTime of the array of relAirNodes and the maximum endTime of the array of relAirNodes?** In other words, the return object would look like:

```
[ { 'edNode':..., 'relAirNodes':{'startTime':..., 'endTime':...}}, ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase JOINS are LEFT to RIGHT. If you are looking only INNER JOINS only re-arrange JOINs such that it eliminate more early.

Create indexes described here https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-support-n1ql/

```
SELECT en.*, c AS relAirNodes
FROM (SELECT rn.fromNode, MIN(b.startDateTime) AS startDateTime, MAX(b.endDateTime) AS endDateTime
      FROM (SELECT an.id, an.customAttributes.endDateTime, an.customAttributes.startDateTime
            FROM my_bucket AS an
            WHERE an.type = "airNode"
                  AND an.customAttributes.endDateTime BETWEEN CLOCK_UTC() AND DATE_ADD_STR(CLOCK_UTC(), 14, "day")
            ) AS b
      JOIN my_bucket AS rn ON rn.type = "relNode" AND rn.toNode = b.id
      GROUP BY rn.fromNode) AS c
JOIN my_bucket AS en ON en.type = "edNode" AND en.id = c.fromNode
;

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON my_bucket(customAttributes.endDateTime, customAttributes.startDateTime, id) WHERE type = "airNode";
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON my_bucket(toNode, fromNode) WHERE type = "relNode";
CREATE INDEX ix3 ON my_bucket(id) WHERE type = "edNode";
```

If need Outer Joins (Requires CB 6.5.0+ https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-enhancements-and-ansi-merge/)

```
SELECT en.*, c AS relAirNodes
FROM my_bucket AS en
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rn.fromNode, MIN(b.startDateTime) AS startDateTime, MAX(b.endDateTime) AS endDateTime
           FROM (SELECT an.id, an.customAttributes.endDateTime, an.customAttributes.startDateTime
                 FROM my_bucket AS an
                 WHERE an.type = "airNode"
                       AND an.customAttributes.endDateTime BETWEEN CLOCK_UTC() AND DATE_ADD_STR(CLOCK_UTC(), 14, "day")
            ) AS b
           JOIN my_bucket AS rn ON rn.type = "relNode" AND rn.toNode = b.id
           GROUP BY rn.fromNode) AS c ON en.id = c.fromNode
WHERE en.type = "edNode";
```

Also there are ARRAY_MIN(), ARRAY_MAX() functions. ex : ARRAY_MIN(relAirNodes[*].startDateTime) on array of objects.

Comment: When I run this, I get the following error:
```
"No index available for ANSI join term rn"
```
I googled around for explanations, but I don't understand most of them :( Here is one that I found: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/no-index-available-for-ansi-join-term/23589

Comment: But let me try out the ARRAY functions actually - those look really helpful! Thank you btw :)

Comment: The blog in the response gives how ANSI JOIN works. You need to have indexes due to global secondary index   CREATE INDEX ix1 ON my_bucket(customAttributes.endDateTime, customAttributes.startDateTime, id) WHERE type = "airNode";
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON my_bucket(toNode, fromNode) WHERE type = "relNode";
CREATE INDEX ix3 ON my_bucket(id) WHERE type = "edNode";

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help! I tried it with the ARRAY functions and it worked! Accepted your answer :)